# I can't get fix() and names() to work (as intended in ISLR) on data set

Tags: r

I'm trying to work on data set `Boston` from `MASS` library following ISLR handbook. I am able to load `MASS` library with `library()` (I believe I can, because I ? `Boston` provides description of this data set), however I have problems with next steps.

ISLR is telling me to use

```
fix(Boston)
names(Boston)
```

First to learn more about data set, second to get names from it (I was able to perform both on previously used data set "Auto" few chapters before). However it doesn't work for me and when I run it:

`fix(Boston)` opens a Edit window containing only

```
function () 
  {
  }
```

`names(Boston)` returns simply `NULL`.

I read R documentation from stat.ethz.ch about both functions, but I don't know how to relate them to my problem. I wasn't able to use any Q&As I found on stack overflow about either function. From my understanding it seems like `Boston` isn't treated as data set or something like this, but I don't know where to go with this intuition either.

I'm using sixth printing of ISLR, related pages: 123-124.

Comment: Unreproducible. I type in `library(MASS)` and `fix(Boston)` and I get a spreadsheet-like perspective on the `Boston` data.frame.

Comment: It did return 'TRUE' and after doing what you just said it works now. Thanks a lot Zheyuan Li !

Comment: @r2evans: I just did the same thing on second PC (using RStudio o both) and got the same result as I described. If you have some suggestions why it may be working for you, I'd be happy to know.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi's comment nails it. If you `fix(Boston)` before `library(MASS)` then it will create an empty function and you *must* remove it before being able to look at the data the way you intend. If your question is verbatim as you typed it, then `library()` will not do what you need, leading to the behavior you are seeing.

Comment: What I didn't do was loading data set first with `Data(Boston)` after loading library. Thank you again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do `data("Boston")` after loading the library, it fixes the problem.

The problem might be - R created an empty function `Boston()` because you might have run `fix(Boston)` before loading the required libraries.

So run

```
library(MASS)
library(ISLR)
data("Boston")
fix(Boston)
```

And everything works fine.